# qpid-cpp-client won't update through yum

Tags: linux, yum

somewhere around last week I received a notification for update, so I've tried "yum update" and that's what I'm getting...

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package qpid-cpp-client.x86_64 0:0.10-3.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libqpidclient.so.5()(64bit) for package: matahari-service-0.4.0-5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqpidclient.so.5()(64bit) for package: matahari-host-0.4.0-5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqpidclient.so.5()(64bit) for package: matahari-net-0.4.0-5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqpidcommon.so.5()(64bit) for package: matahari-service-0.4.0-5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqpidcommon.so.5()(64bit) for package: matahari-host-0.4.0-5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqpidcommon.so.5()(64bit) for package: matahari-net-0.4.0-5.el6.x86_64
---> Package qpid-cpp-client.x86_64 0:0.14-22.el6_3 will be an update
---> Package qpid-cpp-client-ssl.x86_64 0:0.10-3.el6 will be updated
---> Package qpid-cpp-client-ssl.x86_64 0:0.14-22.el6_3 will be an update
---> Package qpid-qmf.x86_64 0:0.10-6.el6 will be updated
---> Package qpid-qmf.x86_64 0:0.14-14.el6_3 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: matahari-net-0.4.0-5.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-ScientificLinux-201107271550.x86_64)
           Requires: libqpidcommon.so.5()(64bit)
           Removing: qpid-cpp-client-0.10-3.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-ScientificLinux-201107271550.x86_64)
               libqpidcommon.so.5()(64bit)
           Updated By: qpid-cpp-client-0.14-22.el6_3.x86_64 (sl-security)
               Not found
Error: Package: matahari-net-0.4.0-5.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-ScientificLinux-201107271550.x86_64)
           Requires: libqpidclient.so.5()(64bit)
           Removing: qpid-cpp-client-0.10-3.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-ScientificLinux-201107271550.x86_64)
               libqpidclient.so.5()(64bit)
           Updated By: qpid-cpp-client-0.14-22.el6_3.x86_64 (sl-security)
               Not found
Error: Package: matahari-service-0.4.0-5.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-ScientificLinux-201107271550.x86_64)
           Requires: libqpidclient.so.5()(64bit)
           Removing: qpid-cpp-client-0.10-3.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-ScientificLinux-201107271550.x86_64)
               libqpidclient.so.5()(64bit)
           Updated By: qpid-cpp-client-0.14-22.el6_3.x86_64 (sl-security)
               Not found
Error: Package: matahari-service-0.4.0-5.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-ScientificLinux-201107271550.x86_64)
           Requires: libqpidcommon.so.5()(64bit)
           Removing: qpid-cpp-client-0.10-3.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-ScientificLinux-201107271550.x86_64)
               libqpidcommon.so.5()(64bit)
           Updated By: qpid-cpp-client-0.14-22.el6_3.x86_64 (sl-security)
               Not found
Error: Package: matahari-host-0.4.0-5.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-ScientificLinux-201107271550.x86_64)
           Requires: libqpidcommon.so.5()(64bit)
           Removing: qpid-cpp-client-0.10-3.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-ScientificLinux-201107271550.x86_64)
               libqpidcommon.so.5()(64bit)
           Updated By: qpid-cpp-client-0.14-22.el6_3.x86_64 (sl-security)
               Not found
Error: Package: matahari-host-0.4.0-5.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-ScientificLinux-201107271550.x86_64)
           Requires: libqpidclient.so.5()(64bit)
           Removing: qpid-cpp-client-0.10-3.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-ScientificLinux-201107271550.x86_64)
               libqpidclient.so.5()(64bit)
           Updated By: qpid-cpp-client-0.14-22.el6_3.x86_64 (sl-security)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

any ideas?

Comment: Run `yum clean all` and then try again.

Comment: I did before posting that doesn't help((

Comment: Does `sudo yum update --disableplugin=refresh-packagekit` work any better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think there was something wrong w/ this package from SL, so they resolved that on their end and now it's not even appearing anymore...

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me.**

```
# yum remove matahari-host
# yum remove matahari-service
# yum remove matahari-net
# yum update
```